# Azure VM In Guest Metrics

Tags: azure

I'm racking my head as I'm clearly doing something wrong.

Firstly, the VMs we have tested on are Windows server 2016 and Windows 10. Metrics appear correctly on the overview page to show CPU Network and Disk.

However, we want to report on Memory Utilisation aswell. So i enabled the In Guest Monitoring under the Metrics tab of our VMs. Intially, I let this create it owns Storage account but I am unable to see any metrics it just says make sure its enabled.

I then created a new resource group and storage account (tried V1 and V2 types) and still no metrics.

I've tried rebooting, deallocating the machines. I'm at a loss as to what I need to do to be able to see all of these metrics.

If I disable the in guest monitoring, the metrics tab load up the basic Host CPU/Disk/Network option. Which is standard.

Has anyone else come across this problem? I've checked and cannot get this enabled on VM's however works on my AppService

Comment: Also should note that these extensions are installed at the moment: AzurePerformanceDiagnostics & IaaSDiagnostics --- I have tried installing these seperately aswell but no difference.

Comment: infact, in Azure storage explorer I can see the table content and its all there! but just will not register into the portal!

Answer (score 0):

You can use these metrics to create custom charts that you can pin to your 'dashboard' and/or set up alerts.

[image]

[image]

**You cannot add metric chart to the VM Blade**

Hope this helps